# how to filter json metadata

Tags: python, json, filter

I'd like to filter some specified fields from JSON Data returned by a Cloud Service SDK, however I got an error because there is always a http metadata in the header of the JSON data as below:

`{metadata:{connection:u'keep-alive',content_length:u'2603',content_type:u'application/json;charset=UTF-8',date:u'Sun, 16 Feb 2020 05:55:45 GMT',server:u'nginx/1.14.0',x_application_context:u'application:8688',bce_request_id:u'86ce3b78-a4f3-4615-92e8-67a907dc632e'},marker:u'',is_truncated:False,max_keys:1000,instances:[{id:u'i-vrXy1oLM',keypair_id:u'k-ks5ARhAr',keypair_name:u'auth01',name:u'jumpserver',instance_type:u'N3',status:u'Running',desc:u'',payment_timing:u'Prepaid',create_time:u'2019-10-21T14:18:36Z',expire_time:u'2020-02-21T14:18:36Z',internal_ip:u'192.168.32.15',public_ip:u'180.76.157.21',cpu_count:1,memory_capacity_in_gb:1,local_disk_size_in_gb:0,image_id:u'm-BvHMmUaH',placement_policy:u'default',subnet_id:u'sbn-76i4csq6v8di',vpc_id:u'vpc-7eie485jvchs',zone_name:u'cn-bj-c',dedicated_host_id:u'',ipv6:u'',nic_info:{eni_id:u'eni-rzhmtw183ffn',eni_uuid:u'4575d2e0-efad-4b28-a26e-6354b8a830a8',name:u'eth0',type:u'primary',subnet_id:u'c684327f-8b05-4d70-9a98-921fd13f0f83',subnet_type:u'BCC',az:u'zoneC',description:u'',device_id:u'92a6c971-f2d9-4349-ba00-304e305c70ff',status:u'inuse',mac_address:u'fa:16:3e:5b:15:6b',vpc_id:u'182534f9-9dcf-48ff-b0a8-ea5c8d3f2c14',created_time:u'2019-10-21T14:18:37Z',eni_num:0,ips:[{private_ip:u'192.168.32.15',eip:u'180.76.157.21',primary:u'true',eip_id:u'78674676686e6757697445777836624e714c2f4273513d3d',eip_allocation_id:u'ip-d8498451',eip_size:u'1',eip_status:u'binded',eip_group_id:u'',eip_type:u'normal'}],security_groups:[]},eni_num:u'0',tags:[{tag_key:u'默认项目',tag_value:u''}],network_capacity_in_mbps:1}, {id:u'i-7QOznBjw',keypair_id:u'k-ks5ARhAr',keypair_name:u'auth01',name:u'webinstance01',instance_type:u'N3',status:u'Running',desc:u'',payment_timing:u'Prepaid',create_time:u'2020-02-09T03:54:58Z',expire_time:u'2020-03-09T03:54:58Z',internal_ip:u'192.168.32.16',public_ip:u'180.76.239.226',cpu_count:2,memory_capacity_in_gb:2,local_disk_size_in_gb:0,image_id:u'm-kgPRuM8h',placement_policy:u'default',subnet_id:u'sbn-76i4csq6v8di',vpc_id:u'vpc-7eie485jvchs',zone_name:u'cn-bj-c',dedicated_host_id:u'',ipv6:u'',nic_info:{eni_id:u'eni-kjtwh5uutkgd',eni_uuid:u'd820a736-a4f7-4237-ad0a-ca3cd2c3634f',name:u'eth0',type:u'primary',subnet_id:u'c684327f-8b05-4d70-9a98-921fd13f0f83',subnet_type:u'BCC',az:u'zoneC',description:u'',device_id:u'9b9fc172-5943-4511-bad0-0a29e7658a1b',status:u'inuse',mac_address:u'fa:16:3e:11:70:1b',vpc_id:u'182534f9-9dcf-48ff-b0a8-ea5c8d3f2c14',created_time:u'2020-02-09T03:54:59Z',eni_num:0,ips:[{private_ip:u'192.168.32.16',eip:u'180.76.239.226',primary:u'true',eip_id:u'6b774645574d524468767a6266524155326f4a6e71413d3d',eip_allocation_id:u'ip-6b2b46be',eip_size:u'1',eip_status:u'binded',eip_group_id:u'',eip_type:u'normal'}],security_groups:[]},eni_num:u'0',tags:[{tag_key:u'默认项目',tag_value:u''}],network_capacity_in_mbps:1}]}`

due to this problem i couldn't solve the JSON data by using json.loads(),is there anyone can tell me how to do that? our business need is calling the API to get all instance information then extract VM instanceID and do next job(batch management, etc..).

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: How are you calling the API? Using `requests` library?

Comment: That isn't JSON. Please show the code that gets this

Comment: the client is generated from SDK

def list_instances():
    client.list_instance

json_data = print(client.list_instances())
s = str(json_data)

extract = json.loads(s)

Comment: the original response is JSON raw not pretty